# How can i listen the value of the input without any keyboard or mouse event by RXJS?

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs

I have a file type's input,and maybe the files can be change by some script but not keyboard or mouse event.I want to listen the value of it by Rxjs,so how can i do?

Comment: Please add the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish, what you tried and where you failed.

Comment: "maybe the files can be change by some script": No code can add or change the value of `<input type="file">`: those tags are readonly to JavaScript for security reasons. If they weren't, it would be only too easy for a webpage to trick users into submitting their registry, or password file, or SSL secret key, or whatever other confidential file they have access to on their system.

Comment: I just dynamic change the "multi File" option of the file input.Like:  

`this.render.setElementAttribute(
                e.nativeElement,
                'multiple',
                flag?'true':null
            )`
For example , i change the file input to multiple and i select more then one files,then i change the file input to single, and the files i have selected will be change to one file. So i want to listen the file change.

Comment: That's a bad design, as it introduces unexpected behavior. Just reset the the input when you change the flag. When user interacts with intention to change behavior (clicking on checkbox, for example) it's better to make her select file(s) again then to make her think and wonder what will happen...